# How to set session key in cookie for every request in jersey

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, cookies, jersey-2.0

I am using jersey for REST service. I am deploying the REST service using apache tomcat. How do i set the session key in every response.

I have tried the below piece of code

```
return Response.ok(response.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).cookie(new NewCookie("JSESSIONID", request.getSession().getId())).build();
```

where request is instance of HttpServletRequest. I want to is there any configuration in web.xml so that the JSESSIONID is set for every response

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking (this holds true for many frameworks!) anything you want to be used in multiple places is best done with a filter. I'm not going to show you exactly how you do it, as it is very simple and it is better for you to read the docs, but have a look here:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html

You can apply these to both methods and classes, so you only need to place annotations in a couple of places.

A very useful thing for writing clean code!